# Editing Javascript and rendering HTML in one window v2

Tags: java, javascript, shell

I wanted to revisit this site to post some recent work I put into [this small project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108634/editing-javascript-and-rendering-html-in-one-window). I was able to add a console as suggested; but I thought I would ask here how my coding stying is before I work on it more to hopefully avoid getting too frustrated with modifying what may be bad coding style. How has this improved? How has it not improved?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSException;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class Jjs extends Application {

    // source HTML view
    private TextArea source;
    // WebView render of source HTML "console" variable
    private WebView webView;
    // console view helped by separate class
    private JsConsole console;

    // sets up main view and fills with red to make formatting errors obvious
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
        splitPane.getItems().addAll(leftPane(), rightPane());Scene scene = new Scene(splitPane);
        scene.setFill(Color.RED);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // sets up HTML source view and adds text listener
    // the render view updates with every single edit: an error resets
    // the rendering view, a simple erraneous input such as an extra
    // character causes a refresh
    private SplitPane leftPane() {
        source = new TextArea();
        source.setStyle("-fx-font-family: monospace");
        source.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                    final String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                try {
                    // restores console hooks in web engine after crash
                    console.setConsole(webView.getEngine());
                    webView.getEngine().executeScript(source.getText());
                } catch (JSException e) {
                    webView.getEngine().loadContent(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        SplitPane result = new SplitPane();
        result.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        result.getItems().addAll(source);
        return result;
    }

    // sets up the HTML render view and the console view using a helper class
    private SplitPane rightPane() {
        webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        console = new JsConsole(webView.getEngine());
        SplitPane result = new SplitPane();
        result.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        result.getItems().addAll(webView, console.getTextArea());
        return result;
    }

    // main class - note netbeans does not use this
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class JsConsole {
    // prompt shown at upon line of input availablity
    private final String PROMPT = "> ";
    // -
    private final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    // array to hold historical output and calls to "console.log"
    private ArrayList<String> history = new ArrayList<>();
    // input buffer
    private StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
    // sets up initial view and adds key listener to capture and absorb
    // keyboard input; keeping the formatting correct
    // attempts to execute every line of input and outputs an error if necessary
    public JsConsole(WebEngine engine) {
        setConsole(engine);
        textArea.setStyle("-fx-font-family: monospace");
        textArea.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent ke) -> {
            String ch = ke.getCharacter();
            ke.consume();
            switch (ch.getBytes()[0]) {
                // enter key - process line
                case 13:
                    history.add(PROMPT + input.toString());
                    try {
                        engine.executeScript(input.toString());
                    } catch (JSException jse) {
                        history.add(jse.toString());
                    }
                    input = new StringBuilder();
                    break;
                // backspace key - delete last character
                case 8:
                    input.setLength(input.length() - 1);
                    break;
                // put everything else into the buffer
                default:
                    input.append(ch);
                    break;
            }
            // re-render the console view
            render();
        });
        // calls render instead of printing PROMPT for clean-ness
        render();
    }
    // restores console hooks in web engine after crash
    public void setConsole(WebEngine engine) {
        JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
        window.setMember("console", new Console());
    }
    // getter for private variable
    public TextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }
    // prints historical items, then prints current line of input
    private void render() {
        textArea.setText("");
        history.stream().forEach((entry) -> {
            textArea.appendText(entry + "\n");
        });
        textArea.appendText(PROMPT);
        textArea.appendText(input.toString());
        textArea.positionCaret(textArea.getLength());
    }
    // output class handed off to web view engine
    public class Console {
        public String log(String x) {
            history.add(x);
            render();
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `history`

`history` is declared as `ArrayList`,
it would have been better as a `List`.

But I'm wondering if it really needs to be a list at all.
How about a `StringBuilder`?
Appending `PROMPT + input.toString()` will become `history.append(PROMPT).append(input)`,
which is simpler and efficient.
The rendering method will also become simpler,
as you won't need to iterate over list elements,
just simply dump text that's ready for display.

#### Magic numbers

> ```
> // enter key - process line
> case 13:
>     // ...
> // backspace key - delete last character
> case 8:
>     // ...
> ```

The comments do a good job there, but it would be even better to just move these values to constants.

#### Pointless comments

There are too many unnecessary comments.
For example:

> ```
> // getter for private variable
> public TextArea getTextArea() {
>     return textArea;
> }
> ```

There are many more like that, and it makes the code look noisy.

#### Too dense formatting

The code could use a lot more vertical spacing (blank lines).

Comment: `Magic numbers`: do you recommend somthing like `case ENTER_KEY:` (key oriented) or `case PROCESS_LINE_ACTION:` (action oriented, maybe with a `PROCESS_LINE_ACTION = ENTER_KEY` to do the mapping)

Comment: @oliverpool For a simple example like this, I recommend to keep it simple: go with the key oriented approach

Answer (score 5):

Some notes:

1. What does `Jjs` mean? I can't suggest a name, because I can't understand it.
2. All your `//` comments can either become JavaDoc comments, or removed. I suggest JavaDoc comments, which look like:

   ```
   /**
    * Comment text here
    */
   ```
3. Code here:

   ```
   public class Console {
       public String log(String x) {
           history.add(x);
           render();
           return x;
       }
   }
   ```

   Two things:

   1. As @janos notes, more spaces.
   2. Why is it a `public` class? Since the class is not used outside of your program, make it either `private` or default level.

Comment: My guess on 1, is JavaJavascript, as it is a Java program to edit Javascript code...

Comment: Jjs - Java-JavaScript